# Apache cxf server asynchronously request handling

Tags: java, apache, asynchronous, cxf

Hi i need to implement asynchronously handle request in apache cxf server.So far i thought i need to add `AsyncResponse` to request.But it didn't work.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
void sample(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse);

@Override
    public void sample(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
                asyncResponse.resume("Sample");
            }
        });

    }
```

When i send request to end point it will throw exception.

```
WebApplicationExceptionMapper - WebApplicationException has been caught, status: 415 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1054) 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:614) 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:578) 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:238) 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:89) 
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262) 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122) 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:344) 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:310) 
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:943) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:879) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:345) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:919) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
```

I want to know the way i implemented asynchronously is correct and if it is the way what is the issue with my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer. Your implementation looks fine, by looking at the stack trace it seems server failed to understand the request properly. Please check in web.xml if there is any filter you are using. Filter should have this property ( true ) to support Asynchronous call.

your filter should should be looking like this..

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>XXXXXX</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xxx.xxx.xxx.XXXXXX</filter-class>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```